# FontAwesome not working with Vue3/TS over undefined props

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs3

Vue 3 + TypeScript. Trying to get fontawesome to work.

The following code results in errors in devtools (while the cli is
clean) - seems like props are undefined, so I tried various types of binding as well: `:icon="['fa', 'redo']"` - to no avail.

True that I am also getting a TS2307 over the `vue-fontawesome`
import, even though the package is installed and the `index.d.ts` with
correct member export `export const FontAwesomeIcon` is there. (v. 2.0.2)

Any clue on what is going wrong?

**main.ts**

```
// font-awesome
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'; // <-- TS2307 squiggles
import { faRedo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faRedo);

// bootstrap
createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
    .mount('#app');
```

**reload.vue** (custom component)

```
<template>
  <span @click="doReload">
    Reload
    <font-awesome-icon icon="redo" />
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Reload',
  setup(props, context) {
    const doReload = () => {
      context.emit('reload');
    };

    return {
      doReload,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have this exact same issue, I followed the answer below and installed the prerelease, but it is still not working.

Comment: Of course as soon as I comment, I figure out the issue. If you installed the wrong version of vue-fontawesome, make sure to run yarn cache clean.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm actually not sure it's the only reason here, but: 2.0.2 version of `vue-fontawesome` actually has Vue **2** is its peer dependency, and you mentioned Vue 3 is used in your project. Quoting their doc:

**Using Vue 2.x**

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@latest
```

**Using Vue 3.x**

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@prerelease
```

The latter installs version 3.0.0-3, not 2.0.2.

Comment: You, man. You, have just saved my day. Massive Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This was the issue. The FA docs could be better.

Comment: Still relevant as of November 2022, for those who are dealing with the same issue.